# How can I cumulatively apply a custom function to a vector in R? In an efficient and idiomatic way?

Tags: r, vectorization

I know the function `cumsum` in R which compute a cumulative sum of its vector argument.

I need to "cumulatively apply" not the sum function but a generic function, in my specific case, the `quantile` function.

My current solution is based on a loop:

```
set.seed(42)
df<-data.frame(measurement=rnorm(1000),upper=0,lower=0)
for ( r in seq(1,nrow(df))){
  df$upper[r]<-quantile(df[seq(1,r),"measurement"],c(.99))
  df$lower[r]<-quantile(df[seq(1,r),"measurement"],c(.01))
}

x=seq(1,nrow(df))
plot(df$measurement,type="l",col="grey")
lines(x,df$upper,col="red")
lines(x,df$lower,col="blue")
```

[image]

It works but it is not efficient and I feel there should be a more idiomatic way of doing it in R.

Comment: I don't think that the `sapply` version below gives much of a performance boost over an improved `for` loop  (yours can use some improvement). How large are your actual data?

Comment: @AnandaMahto About 500000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(measurement = rnorm(1000))

res <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x) 
  quantile(df[seq(x), "measurement"], c(.01, .99)))
```

It creates a matrix with `nrow(df)` columns and 2 rows, one row for the 1st percentile and one row for the 99th percentile.

You can add this information to you data frame `df` (as two olumns):

```
df <- setNames(cbind(df, t(res)), c(names(df), "lower", "upper"))
```