# Cumulative-ranked n'th item in R

Tags: r, ranking

I have a list of items e.g.:

```
x=c(1.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.0)
```

and would like to produce the rolling n'th, eg using a function of the form `cumrank(x,2)` to mean the 3rd item (count starts at 0) rolling down the list to give something like:

```
cumrank(x,2)
-> NA, NA, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2
```

As we work down the list this requires sorting the the items to date, then finding the third item.

The built in `cummin()` and `cummax()` functions presumably order the list to date in increasing or decreasing order and then select the first item, but I wonder: is there a generalisation of those functions that would allow me to grab the n'th item, as required?

Comment: Ok, `cumrank` is your custom function, not in zoo. Be warned not to search the web for "cumrank", people.

Comment: `The built in cummin() and cummax() functions presumably order the list to date in increasing or decreasing order and then select the first item` They don't order the list: that's substantially slower than iterating once through the list and keeping track of the largest or smallest value. `sort` or `order` could be used to sort the list, though.

Comment: What is the intended application of this? You realize with N elements and each successive ranking being O(log M), this approaches < O(N log N). There must be easier ways to do what you want. I guess you'll end up doing `sort(x)`, then reordering it, then successively looking it up.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Doh - of course... This made me realise what I was thinking of was a cumulative `apply`, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796710/how-can-i-cumulatively-apply-a-custom-function-to-a-vector-in-r-in-an-efficient perhaps...

Comment: @smci The application is looking at Formula One qualifying data, where I have a list of qualifying laptimes from drivers recorded as they complete them, and want to know the cut-off time as each new lap is recorded for which drivers will make it into the next session.

Comment: So to answer my own question based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/21796782/454773 , I could use the `dplyr` function `nth()` in something like `sapply(seq(nrow(x)), function(y) nth(sort(x[seq(y),'i']),3))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own function

```
cumrank <- function(x, k){
  n <- length(x)
  y <- rep(NA, n)
  for (i in (k+1):n){
    y[i] = sort(x[1:i])[k + 1]        
  }
  y
}
 cumrank(x, 2)
[1]  NA  NA 1.3 1.3 1.2
```

For lengthy vectors, Rcpp resolves the speed issue.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('std::vector<double> cumrank_Cpp(std::vector<double> x, int k) {
    int n = x.size();
    std::vector<double> v(x.begin(), x.begin() + k+1);
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::vector<double> nth(n);
    for(int i=k; i < n; i++){
      nth[i]=v.front();
      v.push_back(x[i+1]); std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); 
      std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); v.pop_back();
    }
    return nth;
}')
```

Comment: Why use `dplyr::nth` over `sort(x[1:i])[k + 1]`?