# In R Display the sum of a vector only for the first occurrence specified from another vector of a dataframe

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, sum

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,13,13,14),
                 y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,4,5,3,5,6,7,8),
                 result = c(1,2,3,4,5,13,0,8,9,1,0,4,0,0,5,13,0,8))
```

above is the data and I need a code to display the result vector. A little hard to explain what exactly it is in words.
But I would like to explain by giving an excel formula. So if this table is placed in the excel worksheet from cell `A1` and the formula for result in cell `C2` is this `IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2)>1,0,SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2))`. result can be achieved. I am looking for a R code to achieve result.

sorting is not required, given data is already sorted on `x`.
I  would appreciate if this can be done using base package.
Also this is just a sample I need to apply it to a very large dataset.

Please help.

Comment: could you please explain the formula, i am unable to understand

Comment: yes Sure. 
Step 1: Aggregate x and sum over y.
Step 2: These aggregated value in step 1 to be displayed in result vector but only for 1st occurrence and zero for successive occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there's an explanation in words, I think I get it. This seems to work, but there are a couple places where it doesn't match - maybe typos?

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(result2 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, sum(y), 0), .by = x)
#     x y result result2
# 1   1 1      1       1
# 2   2 2      2       2
# 3   3 3      3       3
# 4   4 4      4       4
# 5   5 5      5       5
# 6   6 6     13      13
# 7   6 7      0       0
# 8   8 8      8       8
# 9   9 9      9       9
# 10 10 1      1       3 # ?
# 11 10 2      0       0
# 12 11 4      4      12 # ?
# 13 11 5      0       0
# 14 11 3      0       0
# 15 12 5      5       5
# 16 13 6     13      13
# 17 13 7      0       0
# 18 14 8      8       8
```

Comment: is there any way I can use this code to have the result in a vector form. currently this code displays the entire dataframe.
agree that there is typo in my question.

Comment: Add `|> pull(result2)` to the end of my code to extract the `result2` column from the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 mistakes in your `result` supplied (line 10 & 12) as it doesn't match the result of your formula as calculated in MS Excel.

However the following options use only Base R and does the same as your Excel formula.

### Option 1

The first option essentially translates your Excel code into R.

Here we can do a cumulative apply to mimic the behavior of `COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2)`. Got the idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796782/13210554) answer.

Note that `\(x){}` is a convenient shorthand for `function(x){}` introduced in R 4.1 to allow compact expression of anonymous functions.

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,13,13,14),
                 y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,4,5,3,5,6,7,8),
                 result = c(1,2,3,4,5,13,0,8,9,1,0,4,0,0,5,13,0,8))

df$z <- ifelse(
  sapply(seq_along(df$x), \(i){sum(df$x[1:i] == df$x[i])>1}),
  0,
  sapply(seq_along(df$y), \(i){sum(df$y[df$x == df$x[i]])})
)

df
#>     x y result  z
#> 1   1 1      1  1
#> 2   2 2      2  2
#> 3   3 3      3  3
#> 4   4 4      4  4
#> 5   5 5      5  5
#> 6   6 6     13 13
#> 7   6 7      0  0
#> 8   8 8      8  8
#> 9   9 9      9  9
#> 10 10 1      1  3
#> 11 10 2      0  0
#> 12 11 4      4 12
#> 13 11 5      0  0
#> 14 11 3      0  0
#> 15 12 5      5  5
#> 16 13 6     13 13
#> 17 13 7      0  0
#> 18 14 8      8  8
```

### Option 2

This option roughly translates the {dplyr} code in the answer from Gregor Thomas into Base R in case that's still a requirement. Here we split into small `data.frame`s by each value of `x` and then supply the sum of `y` only for the first row otherwise `0`. Finally we use `within()` which can be used similarly to `dplyr::mutate()` to add a new column in place without a separate assignment.

```r
within(df, {z = unlist(sapply(split(df, df$x), \(x){ifelse(row(x)[,1] == 1, sum(x[['y']]), 0)}))})
#>     x y result  z
#> 1   1 1      1  1
#> 2   2 2      2  2
#> 3   3 3      3  3
#> 4   4 4      4  4
#> 5   5 5      5  5
#> 6   6 6     13 13
#> 7   6 7      0  0
#> 8   8 8      8  8
#> 9   9 9      9  9
#> 10 10 1      1  3
#> 11 10 2      0  0
#> 12 11 4      4 12
#> 13 11 5      0  0
#> 14 11 3      0  0
#> 15 12 5      5  5
#> 16 13 6     13 13
#> 17 13 7      0  0
#> 18 14 8      8  8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: the slash sign (\) in the code shows error.

Comment: I like your code but the slash doesnt works for me. I am getting an error. Can you help?

Comment: @Mohit the `\(i)` syntax requires R version 4.1.0 or greater (released Sept 2021). You can update your version of R or replace `\(i)` with `function(i)`